# Selecting groups by a record value, but showing the entire group in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping, crystal-reports-2008

I've looked around and can't seem to find a question that answers or addresses this exact issue for me. Basically the issue goes as such, we have a report we are trying to write, it shows price breaks for individual SKUs and computes the margin at each price break. The issue is that we have more than one vendor for some SKUs, so in some cases a price break is profitable if bought from vendor a, and a loss if bought from vendor b, and in some cases only at one price level. What I'd like to do is select groups (in this case the SKU) by whether it has has a record that has a low margin, but I would like for it to show all the records in the group rather than suppressing them.

In this example, there is one vendor where the price break is less than 25% margin, and a second where it is not, I would like have this group selected because it has a record where margin is under .25, but I would like the rest of the records to continue to show:

[image]

This is the link to the original image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xc4W.png

Further example:

[image]

(from http://i.minus.com/ibbFXxjusemO5N.PNG)

Comment: What do you mean by 'selected'?  Do you want to highlight the row?  It would be useful if you could include the column headers, especially the ones that indicate vendor #, price break (I assume there is some minimum number to get the discounted rate), and the rate/price (assuming that this is the column with red values).

Comment: Sorry about that: http://i.minus.com/ibbFXxjusemO5N.PNG I would have used imgur, but it's currently having a break down. Vendor number is currently not on the report, but it will be I'd imagine (I'm helping a co-worker with this). It goes Is it a kit, SKU, Our cost, Start and End Quantity in the price break, price at that level, cost for start q, sale price for start q, margin at start q.

Comment: So, in your example, if the margin-parameter's value was 0.23, you'd want Duracell C & D, and each group's records (6 & 6).  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue here is that I don't know the name of the margin field - I'm going to refer to it as {table.Margin}.

- Right-click on the Margin field and select the Format Field... option.
- Select the Border tab within the Format Editor dialog and click the formula button (`x-2`) for Background Color.
- Enter a formula like: `If {table.Margin} < 0.25 Then crRed`
- Click Save and close from the Format Formula Editor dialog.
- Click OK in the Format Editor dialog.

If you preview your report, margin values below 0.25 should now be highlighted in red.

EDIT: to select all records within a price tier group where at least one of the records has a margin below 0.25, try the following:

- Enter the Group Selection Formula Editor dialog (either via the Select Expert, or directly from the Report menu > Selection Formulas > Group option).
- Enter a new formula like `Minimum ({table.Margin}, {table.PriceTier}) < 0.25` .
- Click Save and close from the Group Selection Formula Editor dialog (ank OK, if necessary, at the Select Expert).

When previewed, the report should now display only those price tier groups that have at least one margin value below 0.25.

Comment: Highlighting them already being done, but what Im trying to figure out is wether or not I can filter the report to just show entire groups containing those records, not just groups with just the offending records. Like, group has 8 records, 4 price tiers, 2 vendors, 1 tier is out of whack, I want to see both tiers but not the group next to it that is within tolerance. Is that possible?

Comment: I think so, if I understand you correctly - see edited answer.

Comment: That seems to do it. THANK YOU :)